# SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 wsp solutions are not getting deployed in SharePoint 2013 environment using PowerShell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, iis, visual-studio-2013

I am upgrading feature and updating solution only for the wsp solution package I have.

The deployment of 2013 solution is properly getting deployed using Visual Studio but not getting deployed using Management Shell.

The following is continuing as shown in below screenshot and doesn't get completed at all.

[image]

Can I please know where the issue is?
As there is no issue with the solution. Is there any password change issues as I have updated password for Central admin in IIS and also password at timer service?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the timer service, try restarting the service and clear the config cache.

How did you update the password?  If you did not change it through SharePoint you probably need to update the password on your other SP servers.

Comment: I restarted the timer service and cleared the config cache as well.

Comment: I tried to update the password for the timer service and central admin by selecting Advanced settings-> Logon --> identity and reset the password and Advanced settings --> Identity (Reset the pwd ) respectively

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to change farm account password directly in IIS.
You should change it like any other managed account, at *SharePoint Central Administration - Security - Configure Managed Accounts*.
Here is step-by-step explanation: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/08/change-farm-account-password-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html

---

What about your main topic, first you need to look at *Central Administration - System settings - Farm solutions* for status of your current deploy being stuck, check for details and probably cancel it.
Then restart Timer Service and look at ULS logs for any errors related to process OWSTIMER.EXE.